# Add Radio Button in List

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` and I want elements to be `RadioButton` components using `ArrayAdapter`.

How can I achieve this?

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<RadioButton> a = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    a.add(" // How can I add RadioButton's Here ????   ");

    ArrayAdapter<RadioButton> q = new ArrayAdapter<RadioButton>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a);
    list.setAdapter(q);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom ArrayAdapter to solve your issue. Please follow the instructions in this tutorial on how to create custom array adapter.

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter